# What would be the best way to get the index of the current output of imap_unordered in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

What would be the best way to get the index of the current output of `imap_unordered` in python `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 4):

use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) on the sequence of arguments to your target function, and either change the function to return the index in addition to the result, or create a wrapper function that does that.

Simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import random

def func(args):
    # real target function
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return args ** 2

def wrapper(args):
    idx, args = args
    return (idx, func(args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    args = range(10)  # sample args
    results = pool.imap_unordered(wrapper, enumerate(args))
    for idx, result in results:
        print(idx, result)
```